# Why does sleep mode revert to s2idle when I set it to deep?

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery

My laptop's battery drains very quickly from time to time. I found out that it was due to the sleep mode that was set to `s2idle` instead of `deep`:

```bash
$ sudo cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle] deep
```

I then use the following command to get it back into deep sleep mode:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo "deep" > /sys/power/mem_sleep'
```

However, after some time this setting is reverted to s2idle again. How can I make this change permanent?

I found [this solution (`sudo kernelstub -a "mem_sleep_default=deep"`)](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/fwfehh/comment/fmoih9d/) for Pop_OS, but I get a `sudo: kernelstub: command not found`.

My system:

```bash
➜ uname -a
Linux ro-XPS-13-9360 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the change permanent as per [these instructions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1808957):

1. Edit your grub configuration: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Replace `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"`
3. Regenerate your grub configuration with `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.